# How to increment datetime retrieved by MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, datetime

We're working on a Python program, where we want to increment timestamp retrieved from MySQL and then pick the value from that timestamp. We want to pick the first week.

**Example1:**
First timestamp is 2019-07-26 15:09:24 to 2019-08-02 15:09:24

To do that we have following code:

```
engine = create_engine("mysql://xxx:xxx@localhost/xxx")
conn = engine.connect()

time = pd.read_sql('SELECT timestamp FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1"', conn).astype(str).values[:,0].tolist()

firstWeek = (pd.to_datetime(time[0]) + datetime.timedelta(weeks=1))
```

Now we just need to set up a for loop that will go through all timestamps between 'time[0]' and 'firstWeek', in other words all timestamps in the first week of data.

Any idea on how to do this?

**UPDATE**

```
t = (pd.to_datetime(firstTime[0]) + datetime.timedelta(weeks=1))
time = pd.read_sql(f'SELECT timestamp FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1" AND timestamp < "{t}"', conn).astype(str).values[:,0].tolist()
temp = pd.read_sql(f'SELECT temperature FROM Raw_Data WHERE topic = "lpn1" AND timestamp < "{t}"', conn).astype(str).values[:,0].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Yusuf Sahebzadeh  what you need it's what to increment time when I know the started and ended date and you need do a regular action in loop every 2 days for example?

To do it I use **timedelta**   function.
This is the link to see documentation about it!!
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Avoid linking to full documentation pages without providing an answer to the initial question

Comment: Found the solution. We're using timedelta and edited the MySQL query.